# How to display caret in custom WPF text box

Tags: .net, wpf, styles, wpf-controls, custom-controls

I have designed my own text box in WPF by creating my own custom control template.  However, I cannot seem to get the caret to show up.

Here is my TextBox style:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
        <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation" Value="None"/>
        <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}"/>
        <Setter Property="AllowDrop" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="TextBlock.Foreground" Value="DeepSkyBlue"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                    <Border
                        Name="border"
                        CornerRadius="0"
                        Padding="2"
                        BorderThickness="1"
                        BorderBrush="DeepSkyBlue">
                        <ContentPresenter
                            HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                            VerticalAlignment="Top"
                            Content="{TemplateBinding Text}"
                            Name="content"/>
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="MidnightBlue"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="DeepSkyBlue"/>
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="DeepSkyBlue"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

So how can I get my caret to show up?  I want it to be MidnightBlue so it is visible over the DeepSkyBlue background.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`TextBox` template requires named part `PART_ContentHost` so you'll need to replace `ContentPresenter`

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
   <Border Name="border" CornerRadius="0" Padding="2" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="DeepSkyBlue">
      <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost"/>
   </Border>
   <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
      <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="True">
         <Setter Property="Background" Value="MidnightBlue"/>
         <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="DeepSkyBlue"/>
         <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="DeepSkyBlue"/>
      </Trigger>
   </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
```

[TextBox Styles and Templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752068%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> **PART_ContentHost** A visual element that can contain a FrameworkElement. The text of the TextBox is displayed in this element.

Comment: Perfect!  I just tried this out and it works great, much thanks!

Comment: No problem @kformeck. There are few controls in WPF, like [`ComboBox`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752094(v=vs.110).aspx) or [`ProgressBar`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750638(v=vs.110).aspx) that look for parts with specific names to properly handle them. You can find all of them using link that I've provided in the answer

Answer (score 6):

While the question author has been provided with a solution to their problem, this solution may not address other users' problem. One other reason that can cause that the caret in a `TextBox` to disappear is when you have set the `TextBox.Background` property to `{x:Null}` or to `Transparent`.

This happens because the WPF Framework sets the colour of the caret to be opposite to the colour set in the `Background` property. As these two values have no opposite, the caret colour is set to `Black`. The solution in these cases is very simple.

We can set the colour of the `Background` property to the opposite colour that we want the caret to be, but then set the alpha values of the declared colour to `00`. For example, if you want a white caret, then set the `TextBox.Background` property to `#00000000` (transparent black) and if you want a red caret, then set the `TextBox.Background` property to `#0000FFFF` (transparent cyan), etc.